# Anyone know what a TS# cookie is and what kind of data its for?

Tags: cookies

Been doing a cookie audit on our websites, then came across TS# cookie. There seems to be no description of it nor what it does. Any ideas?

Based on this source (https://wienerberger.com/en/cookie-information), it increases security, if so, how?

Answer (score 15):

It can be from the F5 load balancer.

> The ASM cookie prefix string has a default value of **TS**.

https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K54501322

> The BIG-IP ASM system sets various types of cookies to enforce
>   elements in the security policy:
>
> - ASM Main cookie
> - ASM Feature cookies
> - ASM Frame cookie
>
> The BIG-IP ASM system validates these cookies returning from the
>   clients to ensure that the cookies are not modified. In BIG-IP ASM
>   11.4.0 and later, a random security key is generated uniquely to each deployment and combined with a configurable encryption algorithm to
>   provide a security context for cookie protection. Prior to 11.4.0, the
>   BIG-IP ASM system signs each cookie with an MD5 digest signature,
>   which is verified upon return against a stored message key.

https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K6850